# kendo datasource pagination

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, datatable, kendo-ui

I am using sorting and paging in my MVC project with datatables. So paging and sorting is working.

**Now the problem is-**

I have shown `pagesize:5` for datatable. It shows 5 rows per page but doesn't show `pagenumbers`. How do i show pagination with kendo datasource to show next 5 data rows with next pagenumber.

Take a look at my code-

```
 var template = kendo.template($("#template").html());

    // To Do Item Data
    // ---------------



    // Build the data source for the items
    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource(
    { transport: {
        read: "/Task/Read"
    }, schema: {
        data: "Data"
    },
    serverGrouping: true,
    sort: { field: "TaskID", dir: "asc" },
    serverPaging: true,
    pageSize: 5 
});

    // When the data source changes, render the items
    dataSource.bind("change", function (e) {
        //alert('Bind');
        var html = kendo.render(template, this.view());
        $("#todos tbody").html(html);
    });

    // Initial read of the items in to the data source

    dataSource.read();




</script>
```

**HTML CODE-**

```
  <tr>
      <td> 
          <input type="checkbox" class="done" data-id="#= TaskID #" ></input>
      </td>
      <td>
          #= TaskID #
      </td>
      <td>
        #= Subject #
      </td>
      <td>
      #=AssignedTo#
      </td>
  </tr>
</script>
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span4"> <table id="todos" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Done</th>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Task</th>
          <th>Assign To</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

      </tbody>

    </table></div>
</div>
```

Please tell me how do i show page number for showing rest rows. I have migrated from kendo UI Grid to kendo datasource and styling it with bootstrap.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:Add " ** pageable: true ** " to your kendo grid configuration outside the datasource like:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  scrollable: true,
  sortable: true,
 ** pageable: true,**
```

Comment: That shows pagenumbers, but doesn't show rest list, and it would be fine if i could do it with jquery itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Kendo UI Pager. Useful links:

ListView paging demo (implemented using the Kendo UI Pager): http://demos.kendoui.com/web/listview/index.html

Pager API reference: http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/pager